# Convert List of String to List of int Dart

Tags: dart

How to convert a list from one type to another without a for loop?

```
List <String> lstring = <String>["1", "2"];
List <int> lint = lstring.map(int.parse);
```

I get the error:

```
type 'MappedListIterable<String, int>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>'
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to add a **toList()** to the end of the second line.

```
List <String> lstring = <String>["1", "2"];
List <int> lint = lstring.map(int.parse).toList();
```

This will do it.

Comment: Most Iterable operations are lazy and only executed when the result is actually iterated which `toList()` needs to do to create a new list.

Answer (score 6):

```
final List<String> lstring = ["1", "2"];
final List<int> newList = lstring.map((e)=>int.parse(e)).toList();
```